# How does this skeletal implementation works

Tags: java

This program is from effective java 2nd edition book, I couldn't understand how the int[] is converted to an List. Can someone help me explaining this.
package examples.Chapter4.Item18;

```
// Concrete implementation built atop skeletal implementation - Page 95


import java.util.*;



public class IntArrays {

static List<Integer> intArrayAsList(final int[] a) { 
            if (a == null)
         throw new NullPointerException();

 return new AbstractList<Integer>() {
     public Integer get(int i) {
  return a[i]; // Autoboxing (Item 5)
     }

     @Override
     public Integer set(int i, Integer val) {
  int oldVal = a[i];
  a[i] = val; // Auto-unboxing
  return oldVal; // Autoboxing
     }

     public int size() {
  return a.length;
     }
 };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
 int[] a = new int[10];
 for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
     a[i] = i;
 List<Integer> list = intArrayAsList(a);

 Collections.shuffle(list);
 System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is giving a way to quickly wrap an array of primitive ints into a LIst of Integers. Internally it's using autoboxing to convert between int and Integer. The technique may be useful becase there's no similar conversion between int[] and List.

The fundamental technique is to build an anonymous implementation of AbstractList.

```
public class IntArrays {

     static List<Integer> intArrayAsList(final int[] a) { 
     if (a == null)
         throw new NullPointerException();


     return new AbstractList<Integer>() {
         // code here
     }
}
```

The trick there is that **final int[] a** is availble to the implementation methods.

After that we just need to provide implementation methods of the interface defined by **AbstractList**, that is the methods get(), set() and size().

So each of those is pretty obvious, making good use of autoboxing.

```
 public Integer get(int i) {
          return a[i]; // Autoboxing (Item 5)
 }


 public Integer set(int i, Integer val) {
       int oldVal = a[i];
       a[i] = val; // Auto-unboxing
       return oldVal; // Autoboxing
 }

 public int size() {
     return a.length;
 }
```

Comment: Actually i was questioning how does the list being constructed!. Now I got it after a close look at the code again and again.Thanks